# Filter list of dictionaries by value and then add other keys & values to filtered dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, finance

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
    option_list_dict = [{'strike_price': '1', 'bid_price': '0.25', 'delta': '0.94' }, 
    {'strike_price': '1.5', 'bid_price': '0.15', 'delta': '0.88'},
    {'strike_price': '2', 'bid_price': '0.05', 'delta': 'None'}, 
    {'strike_price': '2.5', 'bid_price': '0.31', 'delta': '0.25'}]
```

How can I filter out for example, a **'delta' of >0.9** and then see an output of the other values and keys that are in that filtered dictionary? And it should not search for 'None' related values.

So the result should look something like:

```
search_for_delta >0.9 = {'strike_price': '1', 'bid_price': '0.25', 'delta': '0.94'}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, and it would probably be helpful to given an example of what the result should look like if there's more than one dictionary that passes the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
option_list_dict = [{'strike_price': '1', 'bid_price': '0.25', 'delta': '0.94' }, 
    {'strike_price': '1.5', 'bid_price': '0.15', 'delta': '0.88'},
    {'strike_price': '2', 'bid_price': '0.05', 'delta': 'None'}, 
    {'strike_price': '2.5', 'bid_price': '0.31', 'delta': '0.25'}]

result = []

for dict in option_list_dict:
    try:
        if float(dict['delta']) > 0.9:
            result.append(dict)
    except:
        pass

print(result)
```

This approach returns a list of all the dictionaries that satisfy the condition, in this case:

```
result = [{'strike_price': '1', 'bid_price': '0.25', 'delta': '0.94'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this in "one" line:

```
[i for i in option_list_dict if
    (all(f.isnumeric() for f in i['delta'].split('.'))
     and float(i['delta']) > .9)]
```

```
[{'strike_price': '1', 'bid_price': '0.25', 'delta': '0.94'}]
```

Comment: I got this error somehow: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'. Any way to fix this?